# How can I correlate rainfall in month t with food availability in month t+1 or t+2?

Tags: r

I am trying to run a time series analysis in order to correlate rainfall in month t with food availability in month t+1 or t+2, using R. Could anyone help with that.

I tried autocorrelation and autoregression BUT I would like to correlate rainfall and food availability using the following data sets ( just examples).

**data:**

```
structure(list(Month = c("Jan-17", "Feb-17", "Mar-17", "Apr-17", 
"May-17", "Jun-17", "Jul-17", "Aug-17", "Sep-17", "Oct-17", "Nov-17", 
"Dec-17"), Rain = c(43, 78, 144.9, 124.7, 86.8, 0, 25.1, 48.9, 
125.4, 185.4, 185.5, 62.2), fruits = c(NA, NA, 14.02439024, 28.65853659, 
32.31707317, 12.60162602, 16.46341463, 21.95121951, 9.146341463, 
5.487804878, 6.097560976, 10.97560976)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for cross-correlations: `ccf(x, y)` (look for it in the manual or look up more details [here](https://medium.com/@jan.seifert/the-r-cross-correlation-function-f5f426006425))

The following sample excludes the first two values because the function does not accept `NA`. It also limits the lags to `-1:1`, because you are only interested in a lag of -1 month. The lag value k returned by ccf(x, y) estimates the correlation between `x[t+k]` and `y[t]`.

```r
Df <- structure(list(Month = c("Jan-17", "Feb-17", "Mar-17", "Apr-17",
                               "May-17", "Jun-17", "Jul-17", "Aug-17",
                               "Sep-17", "Oct-17", "Nov-17", "Dec-17"),
                     Rain = c(43, 78, 144.9, 124.7, 86.8, 0, 25.1, 48.9,
                              125.4, 185.4, 185.5, 62.2),
                     fruits = c(NA, NA, 14.02439024, 28.65853659,
                     32.31707317, 12.60162602, 16.46341463, 21.95121951, 9.146341463,
                     5.487804878, 6.097560976, 10.97560976)),
                class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))
Result <- ccf(Df$Rain[-(1:2)], Df$fruits[-(1:2)], lag.max = 1, plot = FALSE)
```

These are your cross correlations. You could also change the argument `plot = TRUE` to receive a plot of the three values.

```r
Result
#> 
#> Autocorrelations of series 'X', by lag
#> 
#>     -1      0      1 
#> -0.123 -0.322 -0.483
```

Of course, you can also do it by yourself. All you have to do is to subset the two vectors by selecting the according vector position. This way you can cross-check the `ccf()` result:

```r
cor(Df$Rain[3:11], Df$fruits[4:12])
#> [1] -0.1276439
```

And this way you are also able to use all available values:

```r
cor(Df$Rain[2:11], Df$fruits[3:12])
#> [1] -0.1181127
```

Please note, that `ccf()` and `cor()` results differ by a bit. The cross-correlation works differently. It's algorithm is based on the stationarity assumption which will lead to different results than `cor()`. That would become more pronounced once you use larger time lags than 1.

<sup>Created on 2021-03-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>